Why it is required to manually define a queryset in DRF viewsets? Why is not it pulled from Meta's model?
Why is it required, is customary at least, to define a model-objects queryset in Django Rest Framework in model-viewsets? Isn't it more solid to retrieve the queryset automatically from model, defined in Meta class, defining specified queryset if necessary and for each view?
Is:
class HoloModelViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = HoloModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HoloSerializer

Why not:
class HoloModelViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
     serializer_class = HoloSerializer
     class Meta:
         model = HoloModel

I presume that it may be a security-related issue, to manually define queryset to avoid data leakege or unwanted data changes.

The queryset is sometimes generated dynamically, so it is not known per se by the ViewSet what serializer will be used.

But what you try to do is to some extent covered by the neapolitan crudview: https://github.com/carltongibson/neapolitan

I'm actually not trying to do anything, just asking if ther is a great reason behind it, but thanks, that git-project seems to be covering what I wondered about)
